# Replace template Placeholder with Object Properties with Reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, reflection

In C#, I want to replace the string Placeholder with Object Properties using Reflection

```
        string formula = "{\"Name\": \"{{Name}}\", \"Email\": \"{{Email}}\" }";
        Student student = new Student();
        student.Name = "Parker";
        student.Email = "Parker@xyz.com";
        student.Address = "Mark Avenue";
        var result1 = GenerateJson(formula, student);
        //Output :  "{\"Name\": \"Parker\", \"Email\": \"Parker@xyz.com\" }"

        student.Name = "Royal";
        student.Email = "Royal@xyz.com";
        student.Address = "Cross Lane";
        var result2 = GenerateJson(formula, student);
        //Output :  "{\"Name\": \"Royal\", \"Email\": \"Royal@xyz.com\" }"





    public string GenerateJson(string formula, Student student)
    {
        string result = "";
        //logic for replacing the Placeholder woth object properties
        return result;
    }

    class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Why not use a JSON serializer instead? Create an object with the values you want and return it. In fact, given these examples why not return `Student` directly? A Web API action would serialize it to JSON directly. In other cases, `JsonSerializer.Serialize(student)` would do the same thing

Comment: Hey, @PanagiotisKanavos That's not the requirement. As you can see from the formula, I just need Name and Email out of that class, which I need to Hash for Uniqueness. Can you please remove the Close Vote. I desperately need the solution for it.

Comment: How so? Even if `Student` didn't have the exact schema you want, you can always create an anonymous type with whatever shape you want. Nothing in the questions shows that some property should be omitted. Instead of describing the problem, you described what you expected the solution to look like

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That is the problem, Schema is not fixed, it can vary as per need. in some cases the combination will be Name and Address, So, I cant hardcode that thing

Comment: That doesn't mean you need a template. You still haven't explained what the problem is. You don't even need JSON to generate a string for hashing. Do you want to call an API that expects you to generate a hash of *specific* fields? Does it have to be JSON? Where are those fields specified? An anonymous type is no more hard-coded than a `string[]` with the field names, unless *every single call* is going to use different fields. Typically, it's only different requests that need different fields. And different requests are typically implemented using different methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize it to `ExpandoObject` (`IDictionary<string,object>`). Then compare property names with the known type. If there is match between Dictionary's key and student's propertyName. Replace `ExpandoObject`'s Value with `Student`'s property's value. After all, serialize it to json.

Here it is,

```
public string GenerateJson(string formula, Student student)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> templateValues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(formula);

        PropertyInfo[] sourceProperty = typeof(Student).GetProperties();

        foreach (var item in sourceProperty)
        {
            KeyValuePair<string,object> value = templateValues.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Key == item.Name);

            if (value.Key != null)
            {
                templateValues[item.Name] = item.GetValue(student);
            }
        }

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(templateValues);
    }
```

Comment: Or use `JsonConvert.Serialize(new {student.Name,student.Email})`

Answer (score 2):

If you really don't want or cannot use `Json.NET` than you can try solution below

```
public string GenerateJson(string formula, Student student)
{
    return Regex.Replace(formula, @"\{\{(\w+)\}\}", match => typeof(Student).GetProperty(
        match.Groups[1].ToString())?.GetValue(student)?.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This answer is a Perfect Fit as its fast. But, since the question was about the Reflection. Thanks

Comment: @Pratik Bhoir This solution is very slow comparing with other alternatives, but it is short and elegant. If you want with minimum overhead construct some values taking input from unknown at compile time properties, and you don't want to implement get only calculated properties on that objects, take a look at expression trees.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the actual problem is retrieving the value of specific properties to generate an API signature. It's unclear if the signature to sign really needs to be a JSON string or not.

The easiest way is to create an anonymous type with the necessary properties and serialize it, eg :

```
var payload=JsonConvert.Serialize(new {student.Name,student.Email});
```

This is far faster than any reflection code and allocates a single extra object only. If you want to use an API with a *lot* of different request types, it pays to use a code generator or in C# 9, a source generator to generate such calls.

It's possible (but slow) to use reflection to retrieve specific properties, eg with :

```
var dict=typeof(Student).GetProperties()
                   .Where(prop=>myProps.Contains(prop.Name))
                   .ToDictionary(prop=>prop.Name,prop=>prop.GetValue(student));
var json=JsonConvert.Serialize(dict);
```

A JSON object is actually a dictionary, so serializing a dictionary behaves similarly to serializing an object with the same properties.

Reflection is relatively expensive though, so it's a good idea to cache the `PropertyInfo` objects you want and reuse them:

```
Dictionary<Type,PropertyInfo[]> _properties=new Dictionary<Type,PropertyInfo[]>();

...
string GenerateJson<T>(T item)
{
    PropertyInfo[] props;
    if (!_properties.TryGetValue(typeof(T),out props))
    {
        props=typeof(Student).GetProperties()
                   .Where(prop=>myProps.Contains(prop.Name))
                   .ToArray();
    }

    var dict=props.ToDictionary(prop=>prop.Name,prop=>prop.GetValue(item));
    return JsonConvert.Serialize(dict);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the efforts you took and for opening my mind, by providing the solution in different ways.